# Not able to reinstall Conexant HD SmartAudio driver in Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: audio, windows-10, drivers, 64-bit

I have a Compact C770US laptop that uses Conexant Audio Driver. The driver was installed automatically during Windows 10 installation.

I was troubleshooting sound volume issue and decided to uninstall the driver. But when I try to reinstall the driver, I get an "x" next to the speaker symbol. The error is that the driver is unsigned and Windows has disabled it.

I tried following instruction below:

http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/

But I still get an error after reboot and try to reinstall the driver:

[image]

instead of getting a dialog to override the signing check. But the driver is installed automatically through windows update. What can I do now?

Comment: activate test mode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553484(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It seems to me that doing so would mean that I disable signed driver checking for good. I ended up resetting my Windows installation. I will not touch that audio driver again.

Comment: ok. post what you did as answer

Comment: I would not consider reinstalling Windows a solution / answer. There must be a better way.

Comment: it looks like some signature/hashing components got corrupted, which prevent the detection of the signature of your drivers. and the reinstallation fixed it